# Custom Error 404 - OHS

Tags: oracle, apache, http, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have an http ohs that redirects requests to weblogic 12c;

I would like to introduce error 404 if there was a redirect to a custom page and did not display the default weblogic error.

Here is the apache location configuration:

```
<Location />
        WebLogicCluster xxxxxx:xxxx,xxxxxx:xxxx
        SetHandler weblogic-handler
        ErrorPage /error.html
</Location>
```

even informing the "ErrorPage" it does not redirect to the chosen page.

would you perhaps have some way to modify weblogic page 404 and not apache?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in WebLogic server. Update your web.xml file to include this code :

```
<error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
<location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Then create the error.jsp in your web app to display a custom message for instance :

```
<%@page isErrorPage=”true” contentType=”text/html” %>
<html>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for a solution using OHS :

OHS is based on Apache. You should be able to use the steps described [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-404-page-in-apache)

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error_pages/new404.html
```